# How to make a read-only data Class in Java

Tags: java, containers, readonly

I'm building an emulator and I have a class called Emulator which has data related to fonts and a set of instructions that is put into the CPU later. However, I would like to have a "container" class that has all that information so that Emulator is shorter and more readable. Is this object oriented? What would be a good approach?

```
final int[] fontSet = {
        0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, // 0
        0x20, 0x60, 0x20, 0x20, 0x70, // 1
        0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // 2
        0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 3
        0x90, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0x10, // 4
        0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 5
        0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 6
        0xF0, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x40, // 7
        0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, // 8
        0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x10, 0xF0, // 9
        0xF0, 0x90, 0xF0, 0x90, 0x90, // A
        0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, 0x90, 0xE0, // B
        0xF0, 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xF0, // C
        0xE0, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0xE0, // D
        0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, // E
        0xF0, 0x80, 0xF0, 0x80, 0x80  // F
};

private List<Instruction> initInstructions() {
    List<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<>(INSTRUCTIONS_NUM);

    add0Instructions(instructions);
    add1Instructions(instructions);
    add2Instructions(instructions);
    add3Instructions(instructions);
    add4Instructions(instructions);
    add5Instructions(instructions);
    add6Instructions(instructions);
    add7Instructions(instructions);
    add8Instructions(instructions);
    add9Instructions(instructions);
    addAInstructions(instructions);
    addBInstructions(instructions);
    addCInstructions(instructions);
    addDInstructions(instructions);
    addEInstructions(instructions);
    addFInstructions(instructions);
    return instructions;
}

private void add0Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Clears Display
        public void execute(final CPU cpu) {
            cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.DISPLAY).clear();
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // TODO: NO SE SI HACE FALTA
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    display.paint(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.DISPLAY));
                }
            });
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.get() == 0x00E0;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Return from a subroutine
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            cpu.getInstPointer().set(cpu.getStack().pop() + 2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.get() == 0x00EE;
        }
    });
}

private void add1Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) { // Set InstPointer to KKK // CHEQUEADA
    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            cpu.getInstPointer().set(cpu.getOpCode().get() & 0x0FFF);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x01;
        }
    });
}

private void add2Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Call subroutine at nnn
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            cpu.getStack().push(cpu.getInstPointer().get() & 0x0000FFFF);
            cpu.getInstPointer().set(cpu.getOpCode().get() & 0x0FFF);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x02;
        }
    });
}

private void add3Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Skip next instruction if Vx = kk
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int data = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);

            if(cpu.getRegistry(position).get() == data)
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x03;
        }
    });
}

private void add4Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Skip next instruction if Vx != kk
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int data = Bitwise.getByte(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);

            if (cpu.getRegistry(position).get() != data)
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x04;
        }
    });
}

private void add5Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Skip next instruction if Vx = Vy
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position1 = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int position2 = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 2);

            if(cpu.getRegistry(position1).equals(cpu.getRegistry(position2)))
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x05 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x00;
        }
    });
}

private void add6Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Set Vx = kk
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int data = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);

            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(data);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x6;
        }
    });
}

private void add7Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Set Vx = Vx + kk
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int data = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);

            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getRegistry(position).get() + data, 1));
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x07;
        }
    });
}

private void add8Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Set Vx = Vy
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position1 = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            int position2 = Bitwise.getNibbleAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).set(cpu.getRegistry(position2).get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x00;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //MUCHAS OPERACIONES LOGICAS
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx OR Vy
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).or(cpu.getRegistry(position2));
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x01;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx AND Vy
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).and(cpu.getRegistry(position2));
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x02;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx XOR Vy
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).xor(cpu.getRegistry(position2));
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x03;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx + Vy, set VF = carry
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).add(cpu.getRegistry(position2));
            cpu.getRegistry(0xF).set(cpu.getRegistry(position1).get() > 255 ? 0x1 : 0x0);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }

        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x04;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx - Vy, set VF = NOT borrow
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).sub(cpu.getRegistry(position2));
            cpu.getRegistry(0xF).set(cpu.getRegistry(position1).get() > 0 ? 0x1 : 0x0);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x05;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx SHR 1
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getRegistry(0xF).set(cpu.getRegistry(position  & 0x0001).get());
            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(cpu.getRegistry(position).get() / 2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x06;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vy - Vx, set VF = NOT borrow
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);
            int sub = cpu.getRegistry(position2).get() - cpu.getRegistry(position1).get();

            cpu.getRegistry(position1).set(sub);
            cpu.getRegistry(0xF).set(sub > 0 ? 0x1 : 0x0);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x07;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = Vx SHL 1
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getRegistry(0x0F).set((cpu.getRegistry((position & 0x8000) == 0x8000 ? 1 : 0).get()));
            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(cpu.getRegistry(position).get() * 2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x08 && opCode.getNibble(3) == 0x0E;
        }
    });
}

private void add9Instructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Skip next instruction if Vx != Vy
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);

            if(!cpu.getRegistry(position1).equals(cpu.getRegistry(position2)))
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x09;
        }
    });
}

private void addAInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Set I = nnn
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            cpu.getRegisterI().set(cpu.getOpCode().get() & 0x0FFF);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0A;
        }
    });
}

private void addBInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Jump to location nnn + V0
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int sum = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getRegistry(0x0).get(), 1) + (cpu.getOpCode().get() & 0x0FFF);
            cpu.getInstPointer().set(sum);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0B;
        }
    });
}

private void addCInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Set Vx = random byte AND kk
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int data = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getOpCode().get(), 1);
            data = Bitwise.and(data, rand.nextInt(255 + 1)); // TODO: TAMBIEN NECESITA UN RAND
            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(data);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0C;
        }
    });
}

private void addDInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Display n-byte sprite starting at memory location I at (Vx, Vy), set VF = collision
        public void execute(final CPU cpu) {
            int position1 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int position2 = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(2);
            int height = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(3);
            int x = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getRegistry(position1).get(), 1);
            int y = Bitwise.getByteAsInt(cpu.getRegistry(position2).get(), 1);
            cpu.getRegistry(0x0F).set(0);

            for(int offsetY = 0; offsetY < height; offsetY++) {
                int line = cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).get(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + offsetY);
                for(int offsetX = 0; offsetX < 8; offsetX++) {
                    int pixel =  line & (0x80 >> offsetX);
                    if(pixel != 0) {
                        int totalX = x + offsetX;
                        int totalY = y + offsetY;
                        int index;

                        totalX = totalX % 64;
                        totalY = totalY % 32;
                        index = (totalY * 64) + totalX;
                        if(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).get(index) == 1)
                            cpu.getRegistry(0x0F).set(1);
                        cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).set(index, cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).get(index) ^ 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            //screen.setNeedRedraw(true); //ESTE BOOLEAN TIENE QUE IR EN ALGUN LADO
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    display.paint(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.DISPLAY));
                }
            });
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0D;
        }
    });
}

private void addEInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Skip next instruction if key with the value of Vx is pressed
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int data = cpu.getRegistry(position).get();

            if(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).get(data) == 1)
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0E && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x9E;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Skip next instruction if key with the value of Vx is not pressed
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int data = cpu.getRegistry(position).get();

            if(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).get(data) == 0)
                cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0E && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0xA1;
        }
    });
}

private void addFInstructions(List<Instruction> instructions) {
    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set Vx = delay timer value
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getRegistry(position).set(cpu.getDelayTimer().get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x07;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Wait for a key press, store the value of the key in Vx
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int keyboardSize = cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).size();

            for (int i = 0; i < keyboardSize; i++) {
                if (cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).get(i) == 1) {
                    cpu.getRegistry(position).set(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).get(i));
                    cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
                    cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.KEYBOARD).clear();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x0A;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set delay timer = Vx
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getDelayTimer().set(cpu.getRegistry(position).get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && ((opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x15);
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set sound timer = Vx
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getSoundTimer().set(cpu.getRegistry(position).get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x18;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set I = I + Vx
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            cpu.getRegisterI().set(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + cpu.getRegistry(position).get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x1E;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Set I = location of sprite for digit Vx
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int character = cpu.getRegistry(position).get();

            cpu.getRegisterI().set(0x0050 + character*5);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x29;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() { //Store BCD representation of Vx in memory locations I, I+1, and I+2
        public void execute(CPU cpu) {
            int position = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);
            int data = cpu.getRegistry(position).get();
            int hundreds = (data - (data % 100)) / 100;
            int tens;

            data -= hundreds * 100;
            tens =  (data - (data % 10)) / 10;
            data -= tens * 10;
            cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).set(cpu.getRegisterI().get(), (byte)hundreds);
            cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).set(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + 1, (byte)tens);
            cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).set(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + 2, (byte)data);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x33;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Store registers V0 through Vx in memory starting at location I
            int index = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            for(int i=0; i <= index; i++)
                cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).set(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + i, (byte)cpu.getRegistry(i).get());
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x55;
        }
    });

    instructions.add(new Instruction() {
        public void execute(CPU cpu) { //Read registers V0 through Vx from memory starting at location I
            int index = cpu.getOpCode().getNibble(1);

            for(int i=0; i <= index; i++)
                cpu.getRegistry(i).set(cpu.getMemoryMap().getMemory(MemoryType.RAM).get(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + i));
            cpu.getRegisterI().set(cpu.getRegisterI().get() + index + 1);
            cpu.getInstPointer().add(2);
        }
        public boolean validate(OpCode opCode) {
            return opCode.getNibble(0) == 0x0F && (opCode.get() & 0x00FF) == 0x65;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are storing your data in variables:

***Method 1:***

make them `final`

Example: `public static final FieldType MYFIELD;`

***Method 2:***

you can make all your variables `private`and write the getters for them.

Example 2:

```
private static FieldType myField;
public static FieldType getMyField() {
    return myField;
}
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting the field and the method to be static.

Comment: @DiogoSantana, why would that be inappropriate?

Comment: For this use static is like global variable in procedural languages. Check this link out: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/

Comment: I am going to read it now. Are you suggesting that i should have as a variable an instance of the Data class inside my Emulator class?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. And you can always pass the some Data instance to any method or class that need it. No need to instantiate another one.

Answer (score 2):

Immutability is the key word you are looking for. Making your data container (Model) class immutable is always a good design

Effective Java Item Item 15 covers this in depth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a common pratice in Java. Create a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class like this:

```
public class Data {

    private String property1;

    public Data(String property1) {
        this.property1 = property1;
    }

    public String getProperty1() {
        return property1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be completely honest, I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish from the code that you posted.  However, in response to your actual title, "How to make a read-only data Class in Java", you should look into [Enumerations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Essentially Enums will give you the ability to create you data set once at compile time, and provide a bunch of helper methods to read the data you want.

I am not entirely sure if it will help your use case, but it will definitely allow you to separate your data into a read-only style format.

Comment: Honestly not sure why this was down voted without an explanation.  Enums are a perfect use for data which is constant.  By definition, something that is read only is something that is not set or ever changed.  Which is the exact defn of a constant.  Looking quickly at `fontSet` definition makes it look like it is enum like data that you can iterate over, etc.

Comment: I'll look into it!I have never used enum

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I'm reading you right, but it sounds to me like you're talking about defining a bunch of constants in your source. This is a mistake - data should not live in your source code. It should live in data files.

Comment: can you give a reason why data should not live in source code?

Comment: No, they're not all constants. In fact, the CPU instructions are added as a List of anonymous classes, because Instruction is an interface with two methods: boolean validate(opCode) and void execute(). In this case it wouldn't make any sense to have them in a file.

Comment: @kcochibili The main one would be that it's inflexible. (it's harder to swap out on the fly, and it's harder to create new source code on the fly than to create data files) Consider a simpler example: you have a program with a bunch of literal strings. You'd like to internationalize the program. Is it easier to do this with a mapping defined in a text file (in any reasonable format - XML, JSON, whatever) or with a mapping defined as executable code? If you want to write a utility to allow a native speaker to do this translation, would you rather emit a data file or java source code?

Comment: @user3452637 Not having your program in front of me, I can't say for sure but it sounds like you might well be going the long way around on this one. Whatever, it's your nickel, you get to take the ride.